# Add page in Concrete5

Tags: php, content-management-system, concrete5

I am trying to add page via code in Concrete5(CMS).

```
$parentPage           = Page::getByPath("/hotel");
$ct                   = CollectionType::getByHandle("products");
$data                 = array();
$data['cName']        = 'New Page';
$data['cDescription'] = 'Description here';
$newPage              = $parentPage->add($ct, $data);
```

But I get MySql error:

```
mysql error: [1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1] in EXECUTE("select max(cDisplayOrder) from Pages where cParentID = LIMIT 1")
```

And also How can I add an Attribute when created page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL error implies to me that the $parentPage wasn't instantiated properly. C5 is confusing in that the `Page::getBy...()` and a few others will return an object even if the page doesn't exist -- it's your responsibility to check it for errors.

Are you expecting that `/hotel` exists? You have to create it first. You should `var_dump($parentPage)` after you've loaded it.